# Symfony2 passing data between bundles & controllers

Tags: symfony, controller, bundle

this is more of a 'best practice' question than an actual problem:

I'm working on a project in Symfony 2 and I've built a bundle to handle all of my webservices. Basically one controller takes some JSON data, sends it off to another controller to check it matches a described format, then off to another controller to handle the database calls and eventually back to the initial controller to return a JSON response.

I'm sending data between controllers by doing something like this:

```
$controller = new \Acme\myBundle\Controller\DefaultController;
$response = $controller->function();
```

This works correctly, but I keep coming across one problem. In the controller I pass data to I need to instantiate AppKernel and call the boot function for any Symfony function to work. This to me seems a little bit silly which leads me to believe I may be doing this all wrong.

Any suggestions or tips appreciated!

**EDIT/UPDATE**
Thank you all for the comments. I have set up my controllers as services, the services are working but I am still needing to manually boot/instantiate the kernel when I call a service from inside a service.

```
#config.yml
# API Services
services:
service.handler:
    class: Acme\APIBundle\Controller\ServicesController
    arguments:
        container: "@service_container"

service.definitions:
    class: Acme\APIBundle\Controller\DefinitionController
    arguments:
        container: "@service_container"
```

From another bundles controller I can then call a function from either of those services without problem:

```
 $test = $this->get("service.handler")->testFunction();
 $test2 = $this->get("service.definitions")->anotherTestFunction();
```

Where I DO have a problem is if I call a function inside of one service, then try to call another service from inside that service I get the following PHP error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php on line 188
```

I can avoid that error by using this function and calling it rather than using $this

```
    public function bootKernel(){
//boot kernel
    $controller = new \Acme\myBundle\Controller\DefaultController; 
    $kernel = new \AppKernel('dev', true);$kernel->loadClassCache(); 
    $kernel->boot(); 
    $controller->setContainer($kernel->getContainer());
    return($controller);    
}
```

I guess my solution 'works' but it certainly doesn't seem an efficient way to do things.

**EDIT 2:**
If I stick this at the top of the class then modify the service call it seems to work... Still not sure if this is the best way to do things.

```
    protected $container;

public function __construct($container) {
    $this->container= $container;
}
```

Comment: I think the [forwarding](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#forwarding) may be an option here.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html) to handle your different methods?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd go down the [controller-as-a-service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html) route with the above.  Say you have to call 3 methods as part of your processing. Let's call them `foo()`, `bar()` and `something()`.  Each of these methods are in separate controllers:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

class FooController
{
    public function __construct($container, ...)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        // ... deal with any more arguments etc here
    }

    public function foo($params)
    {
        // ...
        return $x;
    }

    protected function get($service)
    {
        return $this->container->get($service);
    }
}
```

Ditto for the `bar()` and `something()` methods, each in their own controller.  Then, add them to your application as a service. Eg in your `config.yml` (other methods available):

```
services:
    my.foo.service:
        class: Acme\FooBundle\Controller\FooController
        arguments:
            container: "@service_container"
```

See the Symfony docs for [more details](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container) about how you can construct this entry, including injecting any dependencies such as an entity manager or similar.  Now, you can get an instance of this from the container:

```
public function yourMainAction()
{
    // ...

    $newData = $this->get("my.foo.service")->fooAction($someData);

    // ...

    return new Response(json_encode($newData), ...);
}
```

Likewise again for `BarController` and `SomethingController`.  The advantage now is that this service can be made available at any point in your application (whether via the container as above, or as an injected service), across bundles, without needing to instantiate the class manually yourself and provide any dependencies.

For more information about the container etc, the Symfony docs have a [good section](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/service_container.html) on it (referenced in the link above).

**Edit**: Adjusted the code example to include details of passing in arguments into the service. Also added a convenience `get()` method to retrieve services from the container.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Rich. I've actually attempted using controllers as as services but ran into the exact same problem. If I call one controller as a service, then from inside that controller call another controller as a service I still need to boot the kernel each time. I've read through the docs and I'm not entirely sure which 'dependencies' I need to be setting to avoid running my boot function every time.

Comment: Without instantiating the the kernel I get this error: 
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /Users/greg/Repos/Acme/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php on line 188

Comment: Are your bundles added correctly to your kernel? Inside `AppKernel.php`? They should automatically be booted if you've added them in here.

Comment: Yep, I've added the one bundle that contains each controller to AppKernel. I've set up each service and attempted to call then directly from a controller, and they work. I.E: Service points to foo controller:     

$testvar = $this->get("service.foo")->testFunc();
    
inside foo controller I call the bar controller

$testvar = $this->get("service.bar")->testFunc();

both called directly work, but as soon as I put one inside the other they don't work without booting the kernel. 

Hope that makes sense...

Comment: @whistlergreg Can you adjust your question or post a gist with what you're now doing?

Comment: @whistlergreg Yes - sorry, I should have been a bit more explicit as regards the constructor.  Your 2nd edit is the way forward - your service is passed any arguments into the constructor.  Then you can use those arguments. I'll update my code example above.

Comment: Thank you. One last question - why do I need to the __contruct function when calling a service from inside of a service but not directly?

Comment: Another problem: If I access the service with the __construct function directly I get a warning saying the argument ($container) is not set. I've read through the service container section of the docs multiple times but it certainly isn't clear on this stuff.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling the __construct() method at all, the DI container does this for you when creating the service (assuming you've  configured it accordingly). Just get the service from the container, and call your methods directly on the service. Let the container handle the DI part :-)

Comment: Inside the one controller I have functions accessed by a 'service' and functions that are sent POST data via routing.yml (AJAX calls). If I hit those functions as a service they work correctly with the __contruct function at the top, however if I access through a route (AJAX post data) I get the error missing argument. I'm assuming I need to split these functions into separate controllers?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8625/discussion-between-richsage-and-whistlergreg)

Comment: I read in the lastest documentation that controller as a a service is not a recommended pattern. Then what could be the proper way to share code logic between an AuthenticationSuccessListener and a controller ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use controller as a [service](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/service_container.html).