# Symfony2 passing variables $_post

Tags: php, forms, symfony, variables, post

I have a form which upon submit must redirect to another form to complete further details.

My problem is that i cant find out how to pass the post variables from the first form to the second.

In my controller I have something like this :

```
$urls = $_POST['app_frontbundle_urls']['urls'];
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();
// var_dump($urls);die();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('purchase_new'));
```

I cant use an array to pass the variables in GET as I absolutely need these variables in post as there will be a hidden field and a textarea

How can i do this ?

My var_dump here does print my variables but how to get it to the other controller?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store them in the session or the request ? And you flush the session/request once you used them.

Comment: do you mean to do something like this :


    $urls = $_POST['app_frontbundle_urls']['urls'];
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
    // var_dump($urls);die();
       return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('purchase_new', array('urls' => $urls));

already tried but goes as get instead of post

Comment: First of all I recommend you not to use the $_POST variable but the Sf component 'Request' instead. $this->container->get('request')->request will give you the POST vars when $this->container->get('request')->query will give you the GET vars. If you want to pass vars from one controller to one another you can set them in the request attributes : $this->container->get('request')->attributes->set('mykey', 'myvalue'); and get like so $myvalue = $request->attributes->get('mykey');

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must have access to the data from earlier form submissions in order to process the next form submission I would use a Controller Event Listener to load the data you just saved and place it inside a service on the Container.

[StackOverflow answer explaining how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875810/symfony-2-sharing-data-between-controllers)

[Symfony Cookbook article on how to do this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html)

However, I would recommend that you redesign your form so that it doesn't need to know the data that was posted previously in order to process itself. Having forms that depend on one another's input is problematic because validation will depend on what was posted previously. If you just need to kick off a process at the end of the form process then just save each result, validating as you go through the various controllers and then in the last form do the extra processing as well as validating that the other forms were completed.

Comment: indeed i did not thought of the validation. I will try do hide the second form in js and then show it for completion when submitted